# how to set icon button's splash radius based on it's parent widget height in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have created a customTextfield and placed IconButton as suffix icon,

here when I tap on icon button, its splash radius showing bigger than textfield,

here I want to fix height of splash radius based on it's parent.. like if it is inside of container of 100height..it must be set according to it...

here is my code

```
class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {

  final String hint;
  final bool isitpassword;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  const CustomTextField({Key? key,required this.hint,this.isitpassword=false,required this.controller}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
      child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          ),

          child: TextField(
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20,color: Colors.white,),

            controller: controller,
            obscureText: isitpassword,
            decoration: InputDecoration(

              border: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: hint,
              suffixIcon: IconButton(
//what spread radius to set for better view
icon: Icon(Icons.close,color: Colors.white,),onPressed: (){
                controller.text='';
              },),

            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `InkWell` instead like this it will take size as much as its parent:

```
TextField(
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 20,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        controller: controller,
        obscureText: isitpassword,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintText: hint,
            suffixIcon: InkWell(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.close,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onTap: () {
                controller.text = '';
              },
            )),
      ),
```

the `100` number is not important just set a `big` number.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `splashRadius: 48 / 2`

Comment: It worked...but what is the exact meaning of this 48/2 fix value.....Yeasin, Congratulation for reaching top 20 in this month fast reputation growing..I just checked it now...

Comment: The default minimum height is 48(for radius  it will be half)by `Default TextField Height to Meet Material Guidelines`, You can find on [pull/42449](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/42449)